# What's the 1-dimensional topology of a graph?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I'm reading through this paper here downloads.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2013/815035.pdf where they say "Since a graph can be equipped with a topology to turn it into a a one-dimensional space, we can directly apply persistent homology to a graph filtration."  This must be obvious but given a graph what topology on the sets of vertices and edges can produce a 1-dimensional space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe they're talking about the 'natural' topology of a graph as a realisation of a complex whose $0$-cells are the vertices of the graph, and whose $1$-cells are the edges of the graph.

Comment: Ah...that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Just for my own full clarity: Say you have the eyeglass space $C_2$, two circles $S_A$ and $S_B$ attached at a point $p$. You're saying a topology on this space consists of the open sets $S_A-{p}$, $S_B-{p}$, ${p}$, $C_2$, and $0$?

Comment: Sorry no, the topology would be that given by the quotient topology on $S_A\sqcup S_B/{\sim}$ where $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x=p$ and $y=p$. Both $S_A$ and $S_B$ are given the usual topology on the circle $[0,1]/(1\sim 0)$.

Comment: Ah ok, so on a graph with $N$ edges $e_i$ (with suitable topology on $[0,1]$), the topology on the graph would be $e_1\cup e_2 \cup ... e_N/\sim$, where $\sim$ is identifying all the edges which meet at given vertices.

Comment: Nearly: $(\bigcup_i [0,1])/{\sim}$ (Or perhaps easier to read $(E\times[0,1])/{\sim}$ where $E$ is the set of edges), but I think you understood that.